# F# functional Callback

Tags: design-patterns, callback, functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to migrate a C# program in F#. 
The program is a FtpClient that wrap the FluentFtp library and expose the ftp methods through an interface as follow:

```
  public interface IFtpSession
{
    IEnumerable<string> ListFiles(string remoteFolder);
}

sealed class FtpSession : IFtpSession
{
    private FluentFTP.FtpClient FluentFtpClient { get; set; }

    internal FtpSession(FluentFTP.FtpClient fluentFtpClient)
    {
        this.FluentFtpClient = fluentFtpClient;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ListFiles(string remoteFolder)
    {
        return FluentFtpClient.GetListing(remoteFolder).Where(fileItem => fileItem.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File).Select(fileItem => fileItem.FullName);
    }

}}

private static void CreateFtpSession(FtpConnectionSettings settings, Action<IFtpSession> onSessionOpen) {
        FluentFTP.FtpClient ftpClient = new FluentFTP.FtpClient(settings.Host, settings.Port, settings.UserName, settings.UserPassword);
        ftpClient.Connect();
        FtpSession ftpSession = new FtpSession(ftpClient);
        onSessionOpen(ftpSession);
        ftpClient.Disconnect();
    }
```

I would like to do the same thing in F# but in a functional way. That means that I don't want to use objects with members to replicate the above code in a OO F# style, but using only functions and value types.

What is the correct way to do this kind of job?

In the example above there is only one function (ListFiles), but my question assume that the interface IFtpSession could have other functions and doesn't respect the single responsability principle.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things that are very important in `functional programming` are:

- Separating `data` and `functions` (like you mention in your question).
- Separating `pure` and `impure` (everything with *side effects*) code. Impure code is unpredictable and difficult to test, so we want as much *pure* code as possible and push the *impure* code to the boundaries of the application.

Adapting your code into `F#` you could get something like this

```
open FluentFTP

let listFiles (client:FtpClient, remoteFolder:string) =
    let items = client.GetListing(remoteFolder)
    items

let downloadFiles (client:FtpClient, localDir:string, remotePaths:seq<string>) =
    let _ = client.DownloadFiles(localDir, remotePaths)
    () // return unit, similar to 'void' in C#

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =

    use client =  new FtpClient() // pass arguments in ctor
    client.Connect();

    let items = listFiles (client, "dir") // impure
    let fileNames = items |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Type = FtpFileSystemObjectType.File) // pure
                          |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.FullName)

    let localDir = "C:\Temp"
    downloadFiles (client, localDir, fileNames) // impure
    0 // return an integer exit code (client also gets disposed)
```

This is a console app and *compiles* (I haven't tested it). The `main` creates the `IDisposable` `FtpClient`, this gets disposed by the use of the `use` keyword. You can think of this `main` as `dependency injection` bit of the application, it creates and disposes all dependencies of all the things. The `client` gets re-used by both functions `listFiles` and `downloadFiles`, having the same result as your *callback* setup.

Here you also see the pure and impure code separated; the impure being the code using the `ftp` client and the pure code is filtering and mapping the results from the `ftp` (if you extract the filtering and mapping code into a seperate function your could `unit test` this, but I left that out in this example).

Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Hello aage, thanks a lot for this answer. But with this solution I have to open an ftp session for each action. By example ,if I want to do a listFiles followed by a GetFiles, I would like to do it under the same session without reopening a new one. In C#, I would use a callback action that take my IFtpSession interface in parameter(as in my example). Then the caller can call any function under the same session. How could I do it in a functional F# ?

Comment: @Fede That's easy, you just pass the callback function as an argument to `listFiles` and invoke it before the client gets disposed. Or you could pass in the client and dispose of it yourself. It might even result in cleaner code to gather the needed actions beforehand. Then you can instantiate a client, send it through a pipeline of actions, and dispose of it at the end.

Comment: @Fede I've updated my answer. Now you can re-use the `client` by explicitly passing it as an argument. The arguments are now `tuple`s, this is because they are typed.

Comment: @aage, your solution works fine. But In the C# code, the caller doesn't care about the opening and disposing of the session. The FluentFTP library is not exposed. He only see the interface and the different callable function through the onOpenSession callback. Actually, I could do the same in F# and wrap the FluentFTP api under my own class as described here http://www.fssnip.net/k8/title/F-Strategy-Pattern, but then I fall back on OO paradigme. But I don't see how I could do the job in a pure functional way, if there is a way..

Comment: @Fede I see what you're saying, my solution does *not* encapsulate those details whilst yours does. If you want that kind of abstraction, you could have a function that takes an `ftp` function where the type would be `string -> string list` (for your `listFiles` function) and this could then be partially applied in the dependency injection part of the app. The function using *this* function then wouldn't care about the (`FluentFTP`) implementation.

Comment: Hi aage, thanks a lot. Here we arrive at the point. If I  partially apply the FluentFTP implementation to expose only a string -> string list function it works well. But the caller could call multiple functions exposed by the client(get, put, delete...) which of them having a different signature and each of them should be callable  into the same opened session. So, I need to inject all of these functions abstracting the real implementation and the open/close session management.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [Computation Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions) to be able to reuse in different FTP workflows may be the most robust solution that you're looking for. You could probably even use the built-in async expression as well. It could be something like:

And then use it like

```
async {
   using ftp = FluentFTP...
   // do your things here
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Alternatively, you could build your own computation expression to handle all the build-up and tear-down, but this is one of the more powerful constructs in F# that tends to be neglected.